# SQL: Two select statements in one query ( Same Table )

Tags: mysql, sql

InfoTable

```
   id | school  | grade | score
    1 | school A| A     | 100
    2 | school B| D     | 25
    3 | school B| C     | 50
    4 | school A| B     | 67
    5 | school C| B     | 70
    6 | school A| D     | 10
    6 | school B| A     | 85
```

what i am trying to do is multiple select to count the average of 'School A' and other school

i can find what i wanted by using 2 different sql statement:

```
SELECT school,AVG(score) as average FROM infoTable where school = 'school A';
```

and

```
SELECT school,AVG(score) as average FROM infoTable where school != 'school A';
```

but is that possible to do it in 1 statement ? where it will become :

```
  school | average | other_school_average
school A |  60     | 70
```

=============================================================
(Update): Above issue has been solved.

```
SELECT
    AVG(CASE WHEN school = 'school A' THEN score END) AS school_a_average,
    AVG(CASE WHEN school != 'school A' THEN score END) AS other_school_average,
    SUM(school = 'school A') - SUM(school != 'school A') AS diff
FROM infoTable;
```

Above code is provided by @Tim Biegeleisen , the code work as intended , and the result is what i wanted.

Below is the latest question:

What i wanted to archieve is :

Count the total number of `School A` that score is higher than the `other_school_average` .

---

Example:

`average of other school score is (38.75%) based on the table provided , so it able to calculate the total count of school A is 3`

What i have tried , but show error :

```
IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (school = 'school A' and score >= AVG(CASE WHEN school != 'school A' THEN score END)) THEN score END),0) AS school_count,
```

Comment: Edit your question and reveal the real problem.

Comment: i have edited the question with the real problem and the method i tries .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    AVG(CASE WHEN school = 'school A' THEN score END) AS school_a_average,
    AVG(CASE WHEN school != 'school A' THEN score END) AS other_school_average,
    SUM(school = 'school A') - SUM(school != 'school A') AS diff
FROM infoTable;
```

Comment: thanks , but is that possible to add another clause inside the 'case' ? as i wanted to find out (COUNT) the total number different between `school A` and other school

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply , what i wanted is that `to find out the total count of number` of `school A that higher score than AVERAGE of other school` that higher than other school score average .    so for example : average of other school score is (38.75%)  , so it able to calculate the total count of `school A` is  **3**

Answer (score 1):

Please try not to keep updating your requirement relentlessly, which may upset the person working on your answer. You final(hopefully) requirement only needs to be modified a bit after the answer Tim gave you. Here is the answer based on Tim's, which you probably already figured out. Please consider opening another thread should you decide to press another update.

```
SELECT
    AVG(CASE WHEN school = 'school A' THEN score END) AS school_a_average,
    AVG(CASE WHEN school != 'school A' THEN score END) AS other_school_average,
    SUM(school = 'school A') - SUM(school != 'school A') AS diff,
    sum(if(
        CASE WHEN school = 'school A' THEN score END - 
        (select AVG(CASE WHEN school != 'school A' THEN score END) from InfoTable) 
        >0 ,1,0)
        ) as higher_than_average
FROM InfoTable;
```

NOTE:The average of other school score is actually 57.5% based on the table provided, **NOT** 38.75% as you claimed  , so the total count of school A which is higher than that is 2, **NOT** 3.